# Check if the user wanted name is already registered or not

Tags: php, pdo

I looking for an advice to you guys, here is the case: user(**A**) created an wanted title named **Murderer** then it registered (to the wanted table), then now, user **A** again, created a wanted title named **Murderer** (*for ex. if he/she forgotten that it is already registered*), now, I want to do that if the user is already registered a specific wanted title, it will be **unique**, now I know how to report an **unique email etc.(per user)** but, what I want to do is, a user can regisitered only an **unique title** on his/her account. My results so far is that the **wanted title** *(ex. Kidnapper)* is becoming an **unique** while the **user** does not registered the **wanted title** *(Kidnapper)* yet. Can you give me some example codes of how to do that ?(PDO only thanks)

```
    $sql = ("SELECT wanted FROM wanted_table WHERE user_id = id`(current logged in user)`");

if($sql->count()) {
echo 'your already registered the wanted title with the same name.';
}
```

Comment: You should provide some code on how you made the wanted name unique. To create an unique name for a individual user you will need to add a `WHERE user.id = ?` filter to your query and pass the id of the logged on user

Comment: something like this @darkbe

Comment: If you know how to deal with unique mail, where's the problem with unique other stuff?

Comment: I dont want to duplicate the registered wanted titles per user, I only know how to make a wanted title unique per table, but not per user in table.

Comment: You make it by creating compound unique index (made out of more than 1 column). `ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE(user_id, title);`. You can extend this a bit further and save your titles into a separate table. Using a *junction* table to connect users and titles, (columns would be `user_id`, `title_id`) you can enforce uniqueness by placing a unique index on `user_id, title_id`. No duplication, no unnecessary data, normalized etc etc.

Comment: Can user have more than one title?

Comment: yeah @davidstrachan, thanks N.B